# Oracle text - contains search for 'and'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text

I am using Oracle 12c with text.
I want to search for the word 'and' inside my section group.
So I built the following query:

```
select distinct "Id" from "MyTable" where contains("Id", '((!and) within MYSECTIONGROUP)') > 0
```

This failed because of missing escape characters. So I changed it to:

```
select distinct "Id" from "MyTable" where contains("Id", '(({!and}) within MYSECTIONGROUP)') > 0
```

But I did not get any result (the entry has 'test and partner' in the specified column). If I search for 'and partner', I get the resulting column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think `and` is one of the "stop words" so isn't indexed by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: the exclamation mark was at the wrong position. The query must be:

```
select distinct "Id" from "MyTable" where contains("Id", '((!{and}) within MYSECTIONGROUP)') > 0
```